# Change Class value With Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want to make a button to change layout from wide to boxed, from `class="container"` to `class="container-fluid"`, is it possible to change them by Javascript? If yes, how can i do that?

Comment: Yes, that is definetly possible.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: An event listener, some query selectors and `Element.className`

Comment: It is common. try searching toggling between classes. you will find a lot of samples

Comment: `var ctr = document.querySelector('.container');
var classnames = ctr.className;
ctr.className = ctr.className.replace('container', 'container-fluid')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.getElementById("myEle").className` to change the class. The classes in below code simply have the background colors. You can put your own css in place of them.

```js
function changeClass(){
  document.getElementById("myEle").className = "container-fluid";
}
```

```html
<style>
.container{
  background: yellow;
}
.container-fluid{
  background: red;
}
</style>
<div class="container" id="myEle">Hello World</div>
<button onClick="changeClass()">Change class</button>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Comment: Mark it as accepted, that would help others.

Comment: I did. Thanks a lot,