# Simple JS to change field color when changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form with several fields that are required, and many that are not required.  I want the required fields to be pale pink until they are clicked on and then revert to the default color of all of the fields.  I haven't really tried anything because I am not sure how to formulate it.  I created a different class for the fields with rgba color value.  One example I found does addClass, but the fields I need to change already have a class to define their width, outline, etc.  Would addClass CHANGE an existing class, OR is there a "changeClass" functionality or something like that?  I tried to modify the answer here: [Change Class value With Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430300/change-class-value-with-javascript) to work when I clicked the field but that did not work.  I tried using document.querySelectorAll too because I have multiple fields separated by other non-required fields and I do not want them to all have the same id or be in the same divs.

I tried

```
function changeClass(){
  document.getElementByClass(".reqd").className = "ssmall4";
}
```

or

```
function changeClass(){
  document.querySelectorAll(".reqd").className = "ssmall4";
}
```

with

```
<input onClick="changeClass()" type="number" id="certYear" name="certYear"value="2020" class ="reqd">
```

Can anyone connect the dots for me?

I can now get it to work on one field by using:

```
`<label for="certYear">Certification Year:
<br>      
  </label>
  <input type="number" id="certYear" name="certYear"value="2020" 
onclick="myFunction()" class="reqd">`
```

and

```
 `function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('certYear').style.backgroundColor = "white";
}`
```

But if I change the function to document.getElementsByClassName I get 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined"
Same if I try to use document.querySelectorAll (I assume in this one it's because I have to define a variable and I do not know how to enact the bg style color change any way other than above)

I suppose I could just copy the function like 10 times, once for each field and just rename the function and change the id but this seems rather inelegant.

Comment: I think I need to clarify.  I want the required fields to start out as pink, but once each one is clicked, that one becomes white and remains white from then on.

Comment: I can now get it to work on one field by using

Comment: Adding class does not *change* the class. It simply adds a class as the name states. If you're not familiar with what adding a class does, you have to read more about CSS class. Some examples can be seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the background color with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript)

Comment: AWESOME, Richard, thank you.  That clarifies a lot for me.  I appreciate it.  Wow, that's like, an epiphanic moment.  Super good.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you're looking for with pure CSS:

```
.reqd {
    background: pink;
}

.reqd:active {
    background: white;
}
```

Substitute in your proper colours, and if you need you can target just the background-color, but essentially this should do it if all you're looking for are pink text fields that are white when they are clicked on ("active").

Comment: I want them to remain white once clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it without classes.

Do you mean something like this?

```js
const reqInp = document.querySelectorAll('input[required]'); // same as css selector
const allInp = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'); // all inputs
for (var i=0; i < reqInp.length; i++) { // iterate the required ones
  reqInp[i].addEventListener('focus', function() { // if one of them has focus on it
    allInp.forEach(function(element){  element.style.background = 'pink'; }) // color all input to pink (or whatever you want)
    this.style.background = 'white'; // except this
  });
// edit:
  reqInp[i].addEventListener('blur', function() { // if one of them loose focus
    allInp.forEach(function(element){  element.removeAttribute('style'); }) // remove style attribute so it will return to intial state
  });
}
```

```css
input {display: block; width: 100%;}
input[required] {background: pink;}https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59831874/simple-js-to-change-field-color-when-changed/59832111#
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" placeholder="required" required />
<input type="text" placeholder="required" required />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" placeholder="required" required />
<input type="text" placeholder="required" required />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: @maxpunches is this what you wanted?

Comment: No, A. Meshu, that makes whatever field I clicked on last white and the rest red, or restores the default behavior if a non-reqd field is clicked.  Chalk that up to my poor explanation.  I got it now though. Thank you!